# Ip of the box I am logged in as

Tags: ssh, linux-server

I am usually sshed into different boxes and i forgot what ip I am logged into sometimes. Is there a command I can type to give me the ip on the box I am on.

```
cat /etc/*release
CentOS release 5 (Final)
```

this failed

```
ifconfig | more
bash: ifconfig: command not found
```

Comment: serverfault.com is better place for this question.

Answer (score 3):

how about `/sbin/ifconfig`?

Answer (score 2):

`ifconfig` is probably not in your path. Try `/sbin/ifconfig` instead and/or adjust your `$PATH`.

Comment: Absolutely correct, I just had to do this same exact thing on a machine yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I use PuTTY and a unique config file for each host/ip. Lets me permanently set the title bar of the terminal window to anything, like for example the terminal host name and ip. Under Window->Behaviour. Very helpful.

-- pete